# How do i fix the selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element making a sneaker bot

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, bots, webautomation

I am trying to make a sneaker bot using selenium and python, so I made a gui using tkinter where the user can enter all their information and then it automatically inputs it into a websites checkout page to speed up the process, but the information that the user enters is not transmitting from the tkinter entry into the text field in the websites checkout section. Here is a link to the website checkout so you can better understand what I am saying.
https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout

And here is the code that i have been trying to use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("450x200")

def fetchName(Name):
user = Name.get()
print(user)

def Supreme():
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/bags/hikdqvpos')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-remove- 
buttons"]/input').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart"]/a[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="order_billing_name"]/'+Name.get())

Name = Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
Name.pack()
Name.get
print(Name)

b = Button(root, text = "Supreme", command = Supreme, width = 12, 
bg = 'gray')
b.place(x = 175, y = 100)

b2 = Button(root, text = "Name", command = fetchName)

root.mainloop()
```

If anyone has any solutions please enter it down below

Comment: "unable to locate element" means pretty much exactly what it says. You're providing an xpath to an element that doesn't exist. What have you done to debug this? Have you paused the program before it tries to input the data so that you can verify the element is on the page?

Comment: The indentation is broken in your code example. Please take the time to fix it.

Comment: You have three (3) calls to `find_element_by_xpath`. Try to figure out which is failing. If I had to guess, it would be the 3rd as you're apparently trying to find an element with a tag name matching whatever the user typed into the Entry box.

Comment: @BryanOakley The Xpath is correct as the code works perfectly if i run it without trying to input the name into tkinter text field and rather just manually provide it.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel yes, the last one is the issue, so should i rather use a .get() feature in order to get the user input from the text field to be put into the name entry box on the site?